# Laravel generates wrong route behind reverse proxy with path prefix

Tags: laravel, reverse-proxy, symfony-http-foundation

Running Laravel behind Traefik as reverse proxy, with a Path Prefix (eg `/api/` => Laravel).

Laravel is served by Nginx and Php-fpm.

Laravel use `Symfony HTTP foundation` to generate route URL.

Symfony is not seeing correctly the base path, and generate URL without `/api/` prefix.

As a dirty workaround, I fixed it by doing as the 1st line on index.php:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = '/api/' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
```

How can I force the full URL or the base path?

Comment: We have exactly the same problem here. How did you solve your problem?

Comment: hey @FlorianFalk, check answer I have just posted

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by Symfony team, for Symfony 5.2:

my original issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/36809

the PR: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/37734